# How do I make this sound?

Tags: sound-design, sound, music

I heard this awesome song and I was wondering how was it possible to make the plucked sound that pops out in the drop (1:36)

It's something like my favourite song ever, so I'd like to know how to make that Niv Rève's signature sound, so I can use it in my tracks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If by pluck you mean the bass, it's the "Organ 2" preset on the [Korg M1](http://blog.dubspot.com/korg-m1/). If you don't want to buy hardware, there's an official VST version and even a portable version for the Nintendo DS.

If instead you meant the higher frequency lead, it's just a hollow wood block sample pitched around and drowned in reverb.

Answer (score 1):

They don't sound like a plucked sound to me, explore your synths percussion sounds. Woodblock/claves and congas or similar.

Answer (score 0):

To make all sorts of electro plucks you have to use a low pass filter on your synth. Then you apply an ADSR envelope to the low pass filter with 0 attack, 0 sustain, and 0 release, then modify the decay value. You can achieve all sorts of variance by modifying...

- how much the ADSR influences the low pass
- the initial position of the low pass cutoff
- the decay time of the adsr

Also for fat plucks you want to play chords or simple octave. In the one is sounds like two notes, exactly 2 octaves apart.

Comment: just add another space after the '-' to see your list appear.